# how to Make Container() shrink when user scroll down the screen

Tags: flutter, scroll, containers, expand, shrink

[image]

i wanna shrink [ Description section ] when user scroll down.
like sliver appbar but reversed.
i expected to find flutter widget like sliver bottombar and i disappointed.
I want  to Make Container() shrink when user scroll down the screen
and scroll up starting position make Container() expanded as first time.
How can i do this??

Answer (score 2):

You could use AnimatedContainer https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/animated-container (doc)

Also, you must use ScrollController https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html (doc).
To listen for the scroll event, and each time when a user scrolls down/up maybe in some cases left/right, you will recalculate the height of your AnimatedContainer, and set a new state.